# Difference between Non-Interactive Secure Multiparty Computation (NISMPC) and Fully Homomorphic Encryption (FHE)

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, multiparty-computation

Until recently, I only knew about SMPC* and FHE, but now I just encountered the term NISMPC. I was wondering what is their difference and what is their difference in their use cases?

- Sometimes in bibliography, SMPC is referred to just as MPC referring to the same thing.

Comment: Can you link where you've seen this term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my best knowledge, the notion of non-interactive secure multiparty computation was introduced by [Beimel et. al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/960.pdf). In the original paper,

> ... It (NIMPC) can also be viewed as a simpler
> and weaker variant of the recently introduced notion of multi-input functional encryption...

And multi-input functional encryption (MI-FE) is first introduced in [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/727.pdf).

> Multi-input functional is a very general tool for computing
> on encrypting data, which allows for mining aggregate information from several different data
> sources (rather than just a single source as in single input functional encryption).

For a particular use cas, say $n$ parties, each holding a secret $x_i$, want to perform secure computations on $f(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$. For FHE, we first create a key pair $(\mathsf{sk}, \mathsf{pk})$, and then let each party encrypt its message with **the same encryption key** $c_i\gets\mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{pk}, x_i)$, and evaluate the output ciphers.

For MI-FE, we first create a master key $\mathsf{msk}$, and then derivate $n$ **different encryption keys** (denoted as $\mathsf{ek}_i$). Each party then performs $c_i\gets \mathsf{Enc}(\mathsf{ek}_i, x_i)$, and then performs $\mathsf{output}\gets\mathsf{MIFE}(c_1,\ldots, c_n)$.